# What does it mean by activate a blockchain channel?

Tags: blockchain, erc-20

I made a sizable quantity withdrawal from a wallet.  It got stuck in the channel since it never arrived at the destination address.  The destination address is correctly specified.  The withdrawal has been stuck in the channel for over a month now.  A customer service of the platform A that hosts my account suggests that I need activate the blockchain channel by initiating a transaction from an external wallet to my wallet on platform A to pullback the stuck withdrawal.  This idea does not seem intuitive and dubious.  Please help clarify what it means by activate a blockchain channel.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Layer 2 scaling solution or a similar technology? Because when you use a Layer 2 scaling solution or a channel-based system, you often need to ensure that the relevant parties (usually the users and the platform) have the appropriate on-chain funds to facilitate transactions within the channel.  If these on-chain funds are insufficient or unavailable, transactions within the channel might get stuck. To resolve this, the suggestion to "activate the blockchain channel" likely means initiating an on-chain transaction from an external wallet to your wallet on platform A. This transaction could be a simple deposit of the native cryptocurrency onto your wallet's balance, which in turn would provide the necessary funds for your stuck withdrawal transaction to proceed. The rationale behind this approach is to ensure that there are sufficient funds available on-chain to support the off-chain transactions or withdrawals that are pending within the channel.  Once your wallet on platform A has the required on-chain balance, the channel should have the necessary "activation" to process the stuck withdrawal. Hope this will be helpful to you.